# Hide SCHEDULED items in org-agenda until they are past their scheduled date and time

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

When processing my tasks in org-mode I use a custom view that displays my unscheduled/undeadlined TODOs, as well as the next two days of my `days-agenda`. I would like to use `SCHEDULED` dates as the start date for a task, i.e., this task cannot even be started until the `SCHEDULED` date *and time* have past. With this in mind, a task that is scheduled for 5pm tomorrow is not only useless to me today, it is equally useless tomorrow *until after* 5pm. Is there any way to hide `SCHEDULED` tasks from TODO lists ***and agendas*** if it is before their due date and time?

I am aware of the settings `(setq org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled 'future)`
and `(setq org-agenda-tags-todo-honor-ignore-options t)`. However, the former seems only to apply to the global todo list, and the latter is for tags-todo search; neither setting seems to have any effect on the daily/weekly agenda. In addition, the settings mentioned above only seem to consider the scheduled *date* not the scheduled time, so even in the global todo list, items scheduled for tomorrow at noon will be visible from tomorrow after midnight on.

I assume this is possible because the agenda is date and time aware, but I have not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 6):

See the doc-strings for `org-agenda-skip-function` and/or `org-agenda-skip-function-global`.  http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-agenda-views.html

```lisp
;;; Entry in `org-agenda-custom-commands':
;;  (org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-if-scheduled-later))
(defun org-agenda-skip-if-scheduled-later ()
"If this function returns nil, the current match should not be skipped.
Otherwise, the function must return a position from where the search
should be continued."
  (ignore-errors
    (let ((subtree-end (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree t)))
          (scheduled-seconds
            (time-to-seconds
              (org-time-string-to-time
                (org-entry-get nil "SCHEDULED"))))
          (now (time-to-seconds (current-time))))
       (and scheduled-seconds
            (>= scheduled-seconds now)
            subtree-end))))
```

The example in the `org-mode` manual uses the point end of the subtree as the value for the `org-agenda` search to continue after evaluating the skip function.  This is presumably because said skip function *may* move point.  In this example, point does not need to be moved to determine whether a scheduled entry is greater than or equal to the current time.  It *may* be possible to save a split second [multiplied by each entry] by using `(point)` instead of `(save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree t))` -- and change the wording of `subtree-end` in both places with the word `point` so as to avoid confusion.  [However, @lawlist has not actually tested that hypothesis with this example.]  Since users who read this thread may move point as part of their own custom skip function, @lawlist is leaving the textbook example that uses point at the end of the subtree.  The goal is to prevent a never ending loop.